Why vite does not build app.css file at all?
Im using Laravel with FilamentPHP, admin panel is ready.
Now i started to add the frontend part, how can i investigate why the .css file is missing in /public/build/assets?
Tried npm run dev and npm run build.
Thank you
My vite config:
import { defineConfig } from 'vite';
import laravel, { refreshPaths } from 'laravel-vite-plugin';

export default defineConfig({
    plugins: [
        // laravel([
        //     'resources/css/app.css',
        //     'resources/js/app.js',
        // ]),
        laravel({
            input: ['resources/css/app.css', 'resources/js/app.js'],
            refresh: [
                ... refreshPaths,
                'app/Livewire/**',
               'app/Filament/**',
            ],
        }),
    ],
});


My app alyout:
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">

    <title> {{ isset($title) ? $title . ' - ' : '' }}{{ config('app.name', '') }}</title>

    <!-- Fonts -->
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.bunny.net">
    <link href="https://fonts.bunny.net/css?family=figtree:400,500,600&display=swap" rel="stylesheet" />

    <!-- Scripts -->
    @vite(['resources/css/app.css', 'resources/js/app.js'])

    <!-- Styles -->
    @livewireStyles


</head>

Tailwind config file:
import defaultTheme from 'tailwindcss/defaultTheme';
import forms from '@tailwindcss/forms';
import typography from '@tailwindcss/typography';

/** @type {import('tailwindcss').Config} */
export default {
    content: [
        './vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pagination/resources/views/*.blade.php',
        './storage/framework/views/*.php',
        './resources/views/**/*.blade.php',
    ],

    theme: {
        extend: {
            fontFamily: {
                sans: ['Figtree', ...defaultTheme.fontFamily.sans],
            },
        },
    },

    plugins: [forms, typography],
};


Postcss config:
export default {
    plugins: {
        tailwindcss: {},
        autoprefixer: {},
    },
};


package.json file:
{
    "private": true,
    "type": "module",
    "scripts": {
        "dev": "vite",
        "build": "vite build"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "@tailwindcss/forms": "^0.5.2",
        "@tailwindcss/typography": "^0.5.0",
        "autoprefixer": "^10.4.20",
        "axios": "^1.6.4",
        "laravel-vite-plugin": "^1.0",
        "postcss": "^8.4.47",
        "tailwindcss": "^3.4.12",
        "vite": "^5.4.7"
    }
}


λ npm run build

> build
> vite build

vite v5.4.7 building for production...
✓ 53 modules transformed.
public/build/manifest.json            0.29 kB │ gzip:  0.15 kB
public/build/assets/app-l0sNRNKZ.js   0.00 kB │ gzip:  0.02 kB
public/build/assets/app-z-Rg4TxU.js  35.05 kB │ gzip: 14.08 kB
✓ built in 1.70s

I tried to delete node_modules and re install with npm i.
Updated node also to v20.17.0

Tailwind's directives were missing in the resources/app.css file.
@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;

